# Why is ADFS not returning an email claim?

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, adfs, ws-federation

I setup ADFS on our local webserver and setup a relying party trust for a brand new ASP.net Webforms application. Within the relying party trust I added a claim rule under the Issuance Transform Rules tab called Get Attributes and within the attributes my attributes store is set as Active Directory and in the table for mapping LDAP attributes to outgoing claims I selected E-mail-Addresses -> E-Mail Address.

I ran the WIF Federation Utility against my new application pointing it to the adfs server. I can run the app and authenticate to my server and after authentication it sends me back to my page. However, when I loop through the claims none of them contain an e-mail address.

```
IClaimsPrincipal icp = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as IClaimsPrincipal;

IClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (IClaimsIdentity)icp.Identity;

foreach (Claim claim in claimsIdentity.Claims)
{
    Response.Write("<b>" + claim.Subject + "</b></br>");
    Response.Write("<b>" + claim.ValueType + "</b></br>");
    Response.Write("<b>" + claim.Value + "</b></br>");              
}
```

The response I receive from this code is here:

> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/windows
>
> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime
>   2016-10-27T15:30:26.412Z

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://customsts.dev/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
        <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
        <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
  <microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://dev.XXX.net:44334/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <federatedAuthentication>
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://customsts.dev/adfs/ls/" realm="https://dev.XXX.net:44334/" requireHttps="false" />
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      </federatedAuthentication>
      <applicationService>
        <claimTypeRequired>
          <!--Following are the claims offered by STS 'http://customsts.dev/adfs/services/trust'. Add or uncomment claims that you require by your application and then update the federation metadata of this application.-->
          <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" optional="true" />
          <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" optional="true" />
          <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" optional="false" />          
        </claimTypeRequired>
      </applicationService>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="123456789XXXX....." name="http://customsts.dev/adfs/services/trust" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

---

### 10/27/2016 Followup

I noticed that if I change the Global Authentication policy and remove Windows Authentication and just leave Forms Authentication I get this as one of the claims:

> urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport

instead of this:

> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string   http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/windows.

That doesn't help me any but thought I'd offer it up for information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I didn't know this but our e-mail is setup offsite so our internal Active Directory does not have an e-mail address setup for my id. Our admin put my e-mail address in my Active Directory settings and now it shows.

Answer (score 0):

Do you forward/issue any email claims form the used claim provider trust? Try to forward email on the relying party.

As I remember you can forward all incomming claims from the CP using:
c:[]
 => issue(claim = c);

Make sense?